# JavaFX ScrollPane - Check which components are displayed

Tags: javafx, listener, javafx-8, visible, scrollpane

I wonder whether there is a ScrollPane property in JavaFX 8 that can be used to listen on the components that are currently displayed at a given time.
For example,
ScrollPane has a VBox which has 8 buttons. Only 4 buttons can be seen in scrollpane. I would like a listener that gives those 4 out of 8 buttons that are displayed while the position of the scroll changes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check if the Nodes visible like that:

```
private List<Node> getVisibleNodes(ScrollPane pane) {
    List<Node> visibleNodes = new ArrayList<>();
    Bounds paneBounds = pane.localToScene(pane.getBoundsInParent());
    if (pane.getContent() instanceof Parent) {
        for (Node n : ((Parent) pane.getContent()).getChildrenUnmodifiable()) {
            Bounds nodeBounds = n.localToScene(n.getBoundsInLocal());
            if (paneBounds.intersects(nodeBounds)) {
                visibleNodes.add(n);
            }
        }
    }
    return visibleNodes;
}
```

This method returns a List of all Visible Nodes.
All it does is compare the Scene Coordinates of the ScrollPane and its Children.

[image]

If you want them in a Property just create your own ObservableList:

```
private ObservableList<Node> visibleNodes;
```

...

```
visibleNodes = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

ScrollPane pane = new ScrollPane();
pane.vvalueProperty().addListener((obs) -> {
    checkVisible(pane);
});
pane.hvalueProperty().addListener((obs) -> {
    checkVisible(pane);
});

private void checkVisible(ScrollPane pane) {
    visibleNodes.setAll(getVisibleNodes(pane));
}
```

For full Code see [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/kogs/stackoverflow-code-examples)