# Get visible elements from AnchorPane

Tags: javafx, bounds

I'm developing a JavaFX application where the user is able to zoom and drag the elements (all contained in a AnchorPane). Some of those elements are simple lines and I need to have something like a ruler that has different parent to stick on the screen on the same position even if the user zooms or drags the mentioned AnchorPane. I got almost everything working but I have one problem, I need to know which lines from the AnchorPane are visible to the user (as if the user zooms and drags the AnchorPane, some of the lines are not visible anymore). Here's what I tried (not working...)

```
private List<Double> getVisibleVerticalLinesXCoordonate() {

        List<Double> xCoordonatesOfVisibleVerticalLines = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Node> visibleNodes = new ArrayList<>();
        Bounds bounds = rulerParent.getBoundsInLocal();
        Bounds paneBounds = rulerParent.localToScene(bounds);
        for (Node n : gridVerticalLines) {
            Bounds nodeBounds = n.getBoundsInParent();
            if (paneBounds.intersects(nodeBounds)) {
                visibleNodes.add(n);
            }
        }

        for (Node node : visibleNodes) {
            Bounds newBounds = getRelative(node);
            xCoordonatesOfVisibleVerticalLines.add(newBounds.getMinX());
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(xCoordonatesOfVisibleVerticalLines));
        return xCoordonatesOfVisibleVerticalLines;
    }

private Bounds getRelative(Node node) {
        return rulerParent.sceneToLocal(node.localToScene(node.getBoundsInLocal()));
    }
```

So, the `rulerParent` is what is fixed on the screen (is not zooming or dragging at all). After I have the visible lines from the AnchorPane I get the x coordinates of the lines relative to rulerParent - so I can align the ruler lines with the lines in the AnchorPane. 
The problem is that this is not returning the actual visible lines...

I don't need to be able to see the whole line to consider it visible, that's why I'm using intersect...if any part of a line is visible, I need it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30780005/javafx-scrollpane-check-which-components-are-displayed

Answer (score -1):

It's about how you handle the zoom and dragging actions try to use `ViewPort` instead of scaling as with `ViewPort` you can know the translation X and Y coordinates of the `ViewPort` which is the visible X and Y coordinates of the `AnchorPane`

Comment: I don't see a viewport property or method for an AnchorPane

Comment: you can put the AnchorPane inside a ScrollPane and use it's viewport

Comment: you can get the X and Y of the line and the visible part's X and Y and compare